# Why are 0 and true in the given array?

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to test something on phptester.net and came across something I was not aware of. I am not sure why some of the following statements are true using PHP 7.0.

```
<?php

$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');

var_dump(in_array('a', $arr));   // bool(true)

var_dump(in_array(false, $arr)); // bool(false)
var_dump(in_array(null, $arr));  // bool(false)
var_dump(in_array(0, $arr));     // bool(true) ----> why?

var_dump(in_array(1, $arr));     // bool(false)
var_dump(in_array(true, $arr));  // bool(true) ----> why?
```

Why, for `in_array()`, are the "why"? commented lines true?

Comment: Maybe it's time to open a manual and read it?

Comment: Because in the absence of its third argument [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) uses [loose comparison (`==`)](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Use `true` as a third parameter to `in_array()` to do a strict comparison

Comment: u_mulder...classy - vintage SO

Comment: Loose checking returns some crazy, counter-intuitive results when used with certain arrays. It is completely correct behavior, due to PHP's leniency on variable types, but in "real-life" is almost useless. if you use strict method `var_dump(in_array(true, $arr, true)); ` and `var_dump(in_array(0, $arr, true));`it return correct value

Comment: Wow, 0 == 'a' is true...what a messed up language!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)'s third parameter, defaults to `FALSE`. If you don't explicitly specify it as `TRUE`, `in_array` doesn't check types.

In integer context, non-numeric strings are zero, so without strict checking, `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` are `0`s, so `0` is in that array.

Similarly, in boolean context, non empty strings are `TRUE`, so `TRUE` would also be found in that array.

Answer (score 4):

According to php manual (that I advise you to read) `in_array`

> Searches haystack for needle using loose comparison unless strict is set.

Main word here is **loose** comparison.

So, php performs some type casting and compare values.

According to comparison table [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) we can explain what is done here with your cases:

```
var_dump(in_array(0, $arr));
```

Here you compare `number` and `string`. Manual says that in this case

> Translate strings and resources to numbers, usual math

So, first value `'a'` is converted to 0. Because there're no numbers in this string. `0 == 0`, return **true**.

Next:

```
var_dump(in_array(true, $arr));
```

Here you compare `boolean` and `string`. Manual says that in this case

> Convert both sides to bool, FALSE < TRUE

`'a'` converts to boolean **true**. And `true == true`, so return **true**.

So, nothing strange here, to be sure that your code works as you expect, use third parameter `$strict` for `in_array`.